# In html page video tag is not playing on page load

Tags: html, html5-video

Here is my code of video tag but it is not working properly on page load, should i need any preloader to autoplay the video on page load`

```
<video id="video_player"  width="100%" autoplay="1">
    <source src="video/banner-video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Can you paste your full html?

Comment: `<video id="video_player"  width="100%" autoplay>
    <source src="video/banner-video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>`

 just use `autoplay` attribute

Comment: i used your's code but it is not working on page load but as i refresh the page video start playing..but i want onpage load video play automatically

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to autoplay video:

```
<video id="video_player"  width="100%" autoplay>
    <source src="video/banner-video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Here is more about it: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

Comment: i used your's code but it is not working on page load but as i refresh the page video start playing..but i want onpage load video play automatically..